# How does TensorFlow's MultiRnnCell work?

Tags: tensorflow

Could someone help to explain the inner mechanism of TensorFlow's `tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRnnCell`?

For example, if I wanted to stack up two basic RNN cells into a `MultiRnnCell`, what would be the input and output of each basic RNN cell?

I would like to know the details of how it works.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Study this [blog post](http://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-ii.html) as well as the provided implementation. It describes in detail how use MultiRNNCell to *stack* multiple RNN cells.

[image]